# Metaphysical Probability Formula

Tags: probability

I'm looking for an equation that crosses over between metaphysics and mathematics. I'm not sure if it can be done or if this is too much of an abstract question to be asking here, but I thought I'd go ahead and ask it anyway.

I’ve looked through the link below (there are lots of different probability formulas listed at the bottom of the webpage) but none of them seem to be quite what I need.

http://www.probabilityformula.org/

As an example of what I’m needing this probability formula to be for, consider the following two claims:

1) I went into the woods and saw a squirrel.

2) I went into the woods and saw bigfoot.

On their own, each claim could be true or false, but in relation to background evidence both claims are not equally probable.

For the first claim, the general existence of squirrels is well documented and supported by indisputable, direct evidence, which means that the first claim has a high probability of being true at face value. That individual claim could be further investigated and it could be found that I was lying about seeing a squirrel in the woods, but nonetheless it’s reasonable to believe the claim upon hearing it based on the large amount of background evidence which supports the existence of squirrels.

The second claim, however, is only supported by disputable, indirect and at times discredited evidence. There have been many claimed sightings of bigfoot, but none have been confirmed. Because of this, even if I truly believed that I saw bigfoot, that claim on its own is not likely to be true given the large amount of background evidence that does not support the general existence of bigfoot. Even if in objective reality I did actually see bigfoot, I shouldn’t expect anyone else to believe that claim until I had strong evidence that overrides the current background evidence that makes it improbable that any individual claim of seeing bigfoot is true.

So, given that we don’t know exact numbers for claimed sightings of squirrels or bigfoot to use as a denominator, it makes it kind of difficult to apply a defined formula to those claims. Could something be set up to where we assign 1 = “Supported by direct evidence” and 2 = “Not supported by direct evidence” and those numbers are used as denominators in relation to the specific claim being made? Since this is metaphysical issue, the outcomes may or may not line up with traditional statistics with, for example, 0.5 being a 50% chance of the claim being true, but that’s ok so long as the formula can be applied consistently to any claim. So if anyone knows of an already existing formula or has ideas on how to create one, please feel free to respond!

Also, please not that I'm not a professional mathematician and I only know the very basic rules of statistics.

Comment: This should be moved to the philosophy stack exchange. Also, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction).

Comment: Can moderators move this post to the philosophy section or do I just need to repost it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Philosophical, metaphysical, and bigfoot considerations aside, it sounds to me as though you might need to use [Bayesian Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_statistics) to assign probabilities to events of the nature you're considering.

Comment: Thanks! I'll research Bayesian Statistics more and see if it helps.

Comment: @ThePower You're welcome. If you liked my answer, I'd appreciate if you would accept it (click on the check mark to the left of my answer). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a statistician, but I have a little background in philosophy. It seems to me that, since there have been 0 confirmed Bigfoot sightings, then the solution to the probability of finding Bigfoot in the forest DNE. The probability of encountering a Bigfoot in the forest must be measurable, and yet we have no measurements. We would need to assess information regarding a genuine Bigfoot sighting in order to formulate a distribution curve properly. Since we have none, the solution, therefore, does not currently exist. Due to lack of confirmation, we cannot know if a Bigfoot sighting in the forest is even possible, let alone probable, because we have no DNA record of such a creature's existence.
Edit: If you're going to downvote my response then tell me why I'm wrong. :p

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted your comment, but it seems reasonable to me!